# Intellij IDEA 2017.1.5 with the Go plugin wrongly Reports Unused Functions and Variables

Tags: intellij-idea, warnings

I'm using Intellij IDEA 2017.1.5 with the Golang Plugin.

When I run Analyze > Inspect Code > Whole Project, the Inspection Results always include "Unused Exported Function" warnings, even though my project codes clearly use those functions. The same goes for some Global Variables and Constants.

When I comment-out those "unused" functions and variables, I encounter "Undefined Function" and "Undefined Variable" errors, and when I put them back, the errors disappear, so I know they are actually being used within my project.

Is there a way to make these wrong warnings go away, or "refresh" the compiler's Code Analysis? And is this a known issue with Intellij IDEA or the Golang Plugin in general, and has anybody else encountered this?

It's really annoying because I'm aiming for 0 Warnings and these ones never go away.

Comment: You have "Unused Exported Function" warnings. What happens when you don't export the functions? See [Exported identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers)

Comment: I exported the functions so I can use them in other packages within my project. My project has lots of packages for code organization.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to IDEA Ultimate 2017.3+ or use GoLand and see if the error still happens.

The plugin for 2017.1 is really old and a lot of changes have happened since then.

If the issue still happens, then report it to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go and make sure to include a way to reproduce issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, 2017.1.5 is the highest version of Intellij that supports the free Golang plugin. Also, GoLand is not free, so I can't use it unfortunately.

Comment: Then there's not much else to do. The open-source plugin development halted, especially that GoLand is out now, and the plugin you are using is 1.5 years old. I'm not sure what else you're expecting to happen.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I thought there was just something wrong with my environment and the IDE itself, but if it might be a plugin-related issue, then I guess there really is nothing much to do. Thanks anyway. :)